# How to place dropdown inside a panel without hiding the dropdown content using anchor tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to place a drop down inside a panel but it is hidden. A suggestion I got was to use `position:absolute` in the drop down's css, but I am not getting the result.

I want the drop down on hover the anchhor tag and also by clicking the button without hiding the content.

```
<body id="body">
  <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel2">
      <div class="panel-heading-fd">
        <h3 class="panel-title-fd">Our Products</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="media">
          <a class="pull-left" href="#">
            <img class="media-object" src="img/2.jpg" style="width: 150px; 
     height: 70px;">
          </a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">Dropdown</a></br>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data- toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
     Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
     </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">One more dropdown</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">One more dropdown</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          ...
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </h4>
            Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum <a href="">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a full fiddler example (code is too long to paste here): https://jsfiddle.net/td3ogahk/11/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap dropdown menu within a panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559869/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-within-a-panel)

Comment: https://www.bootply.com/Owj9ZxXgYL

Comment: I tried it too but not working in my case please take a look at my code once  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/td3ogahk/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to the dropdown:

```
.dropdown-menu {
   position: fixed;
   top: auto;
   left: auto;
}
```

Replace the position absolute, with position fixed.

Also add a tag *p* to wrap the text after the dropdown. It's always better to always wrap text in a paragraph tag:

```
<p class="text">Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum  <a href="">Read More</a></p>
```

Hope this helps!

Working [codepen link here](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/RJYqOo).

**ADDITION**
To close the dropdown on scroll add this JS code:

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll',function() {
  jQuery('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
});
```

Then, if you want to add the dropdown also to the link tag you have to replicate the structure you have for the button below it, otherwise it will behave like a normal link.

Comment: yes the below one  is working but if in case i added two panels this is not working properly please have a look [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/td3ogahk/17/) and also let me know that can we give drop down for anchor tag which is just above the dropdown button?

Comment: When I scroll the page the dropdown is fixed and overlapping every content how to overcome it?

Comment: @user7628723 don't forget to accept and upvote answer :)

Comment: I tried the update done when I scroll an alert is coming after it is scrolling, how to scroll without moving dropdown and alerts?

Comment: Please use the code I've placed inside the answer: jQuery(window).on('scroll',function() {
  jQuery('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
});